# What is the difference between "web crawler", "web scraper", "DOM analyzer" and "DOM parser"

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

What is the difference between "web crawler", "web scraper", "DOM analyzer" and "DOM parser"?

Answer (score 0):

Web crawler are more broad and traverse entire websites (by following links) to index the data on them. Example of them is Google. Google crawls and indexes whatever data you have on a website. Most of the crawlers are polite and respect the `robots.txt` rules.

Web scraper on the other hand are crawlers with much more specific/targeted goal in mind. They usually only crawl specific part of website that is of interest to them. For example, if you are competing with Amazon and want to price stuff on your website below the price that is listed on Amazon then you would scrape amazon.com for items and their prices. Web scrapers may or may not be polite crawlers.

DOM parsers allow you traverse HTML document using query languages like xpath.